# Automatic UVMapFlat for Three.js

Tags: three.js, uv-mapping

Anybody made automatic flat uv mapping for Three.js base only on (any) geometry ?

function uvFlat(object) {object.geometry.faceVertexUvs[0] = [?]};

I don't care matrix orientation. I just need default flat mapping like 3dS Max, where you choose UVMapping modificator and you get it.

I find THREE.GeometryUtils.UVMapFlat( geometry, matrix ) of mrdoob, but it's not finished yet I think.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I have got it, by adding loop, scaling and offset to THREE.ExtrudeGeometry.WorldUVGenerator.